# Encrypt column names of tables in SQL Server Express

Tags: encryption, sql-server-express, sql-server-2005-express

What is the best way to encrypt columns in SQL Server 2005 Express edition so that no one can steal our database design?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that encrypting names of columns would be remotely worth the effort. Presumably this would impact a lot of data access code?

Comment: I am sorry to inform you that nobody cares about your database design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no best way to do this.

if you obfuscate them you give yourself a lot of pain when debugging. you'll have to change all the queries. there's no good tool for this.

not to mention that the potential dba who'll might have to look at it and tune is going to be lost.

It's probably hard to accpet but your database design isn't something brilliant and new. I'm sure someone else has done it before. So there's no real need to protect it.

I suggest you set permissions for data access, not obfuscate schema. Schema isn't important, data is.

You could encrypt certain db objects like sprocs and views but this is also useless because there are not too hard ways of cracking it.

Answer (score 1):

better secure your database, then encrypt your table scheme

give your application user just minimal rights to your database

secure your connection string http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx#paght000010_step2

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can only obfuscate Stored Procedures, Functions, Triggers and Views.
[Link To MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905202(SQL.80).aspx)